# replace some html content with values

Tags: python, html, formatting

I want to send a verification email. The email consists of HTML. I saved the HTML into a file named `email_templates/verify.html` (path). The problem is, that there are some constants in the HTML file are unknown until runtime. For instance, in the email, I refer to the username to which I send my email, but since each email is referring to someone else, I can't include the name in the template. One solution that comes to mind is to use some formatting technique in the lines of

```html
<div>
hello {usrname}!
<div>
```

and then in the python code do something like:

```py
lines = open('email_templates/verify.html', 'r').read()
lines.format('joe')
```

But this code, although is, in fact, can work, has some issues:

1. every `{}` in the HTML file can be a mistake to be formatted
2. the code in the current form is not very readable
3. code is not elegant
4. for an HTML reader that don't know python the formatting placeholders will be confusing

Is there is any better way to approach this?

Comment: See [Templating](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating)

Comment: @PeterWood can you provide a use example please?

Comment: There are examples on the link and all the linked libraries documentation also have examples. Was there something missing?

Comment: @PeterWood yes. most of them lead to 404s. The thing I don't get here is where should I use this html? As a string? In a file? How to I activate the format? does it happen automatically? Do I need to call a function for that? Docs are unclear, at least for me

Comment: Two of the links are the standard Python documentation [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings), and [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) a third party library.

Comment: @PeterWood wait, how is that any different from just formatting?

Comment: Formatting enables complex formatting for different data types, for example decimal places, dates, or dictionaries. Template strings purely substitute a string value for a placeholder field.

Comment: [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) works well with HTML and allows logic, for example iterating over lists, and automatically escaping symbols which have meaning in HTML, e.g. `<`, `>`, and `&` all need handling correctly so you don't mess up the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can and should be done through templating.
As you mentioned that maybe python placeholders will be confusing but I tell you they are not confusing, templating engines make sure HTML looks like HTML and these template tags look like template tags. Templating engines lay down the rules which placeholders you can and can't use. Also they are way fast than the file opening method you suggested; because they are optimized to do so.

Let's understand by example:

There are several templating engines out there. Jinja2 is one of the best ones.

First, install Jinja2.

```
pip install jinja2
```

Second, create a python file(name it anything you want) and a folder named 'templates'. Under 'templates' folder create your verify.html

Your folder structure should look like this:

```
folder1
  |
  |--> pythonfile.py
  |--> templates
           |
           |--> verify.html
```

Third, put some sample code in the HTML file. I have this example put in my verify.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dear {{ user }}!</h1>
    <h4>
        Hope you are fine.
    </h4>
    <p>
        Thank you for signing up. Here is your {{ coupon_code }}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now in this html file you see I have normal html tags. But there are two sets of curly braces occurring twice. The word written inside the curly braces will be considered a variable by jinja. The value of this variable will be supplied by our python file to this html file.
Also, to be consistent, jinja doesn't allow you to just use any braces. I mean if I had put "<>" instead of "{{  }}" it would not have worked. So there are some rules to be followed.
Read more here: [Jinja allowed tags and filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#variables)

Fourth, copy this code into the python file we created.

```
#Imports
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, Template

#name of the folder where index file is located.
file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')

#This object is needed to create a template object.
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)

#path of the HTML file reletive to the folder.
template = env.get_template('./index.html')

#Data dictionary to be supplied to our HTML file.
input_dict = {
    'user': 'Harry',
    'coupon_code': '12313ASDSA4'}

#This function renders the data substituted HTML form.
output = template.render(input_dict)
print(output)
```

Now run this python file.